# OpenVPN traffic through TLS-enabled TCP connection

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ssl, tunnel

I have to obfuscate OpenVPN traffic. So I created a TLS-enabled TCP tunnel with `socat`, and I want to pass OpenVPN traffic through this tunnel.

Server:

`sudo socat openssl-listen:443,cert=/home/ubuntu/ssl/server.pem,cafile=/home/ubuntu/ssl/client.crt,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:444`

Client:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:5000,fork openssl-connect:117.56.109.122:443,cert=/home/ubuntu/Documents/SocatSSL/client.pem,cafile=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt,verify=0`

OpenVPN Server [444] <--local--> socat [443] <-------internet--------> socat [5000] <--local--> OpenVPN Client

Now in order to make OpenVPN client connect to the OpenVPN server, I have to connect it to localhost:5000. Authentication gets confirmed and but the traffic doesn't get redirected. How can I fix this?

```
client
proto tcp-client
remote 127.0.0.1 5000
dev tun
```